# global variables in wordpress or woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
public function action_save_post($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;       

        $wooqty = $_POST['qty'];
        if( !empty( $wooqty ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'qty', esc_attr( $wooqty ) );

        }
```

This will save the data from a Form field in Metabox in wordpess. I would like to use this variable $wooqty which has a value to another function.

```
public function action_woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, $values) {
    global $wpdb;



    $product_no = (int) $values['product_id'];
    $qty_no = (int) $values['quantity'];
}
```

I would like to replace the variable $qty_no data to the $wooqty. my problem is how do i pass the variable `$wooqty` to this function so that i can replace the values of `$qty_no`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough to me.  You don't need to set a global, since it is already in Wordpress post meta data.  Just call `get_post_meta($product_no, 'qty', TRUE);` within the function.

So, your new function will look like this:

```
public function action_woocommerce_add_order_item_meta($item_id, $values) {
    global $wpdb;

    $product_no = (int) $values['product_id'];
    $qty_no = get_post_meta($product_no, 'qty', TRUE);
}
```

Not sure why you are globalizing `$wpdb`, since the function doesn't do any database operations using that variable.  You should be fine with removing the `global $wpdb;` definition at the top of your function as well.

Furthermore, I would check `$item_id` variable and see if that is equal to `$values['product_id']`, and if it is, use that instead of refetching the product id from the `$values` array.

Hope I helped, if not be clearer in your question.  Question seems a bit old, so you probably already got this figured out by now.  But just in case you haven't.

Answer (score -1):

so you can use the following syntax to set the global from within a function and then access it elsewhere in PHP.

```
    function foo(){
      $GLOBALS['foobar'] = 'somestring';
    }
    function bar(){
      echo $GLOBALS['foobar'];
    }
    foo();
    bar();
```

However, it's not often a good idea and there may be a better way to pass the variable to the functions. How about a third function that sets the variable locally that's called from within functions 1 and 2 for instance.